# how can i get the Principal in interceptor using spring mvc?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I write Web project in spring MVC 3.1 and i implement Interceptor class by extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter and i need to find a way get the Principal.
I try request.getUserPrincipal() and it return null,
I try request.getRemoteUser() and it return null.
I using Oauth 2 and basic Authentication.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Have you solved this issue...? Please help me by answering it. I am also using OAUTH + Interceptor, but not working...

Answer (score 14):

You can get the Principal wherever you are with

`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();`

Comment: it return java.lang.NullPointerException only in the interceptor

Comment: This answer works.  The NPE indicates @shai.tap didn't wire up Spring Security correctly.

Comment: @Paul How to debug this ..?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar - The user must be authenticated first.  If the user isn't authenticated then there won't be a principal. Check that your authentication service is working first.

Comment: I need to do the same but in a Webflux application... I know that the ReactiveSecurityContextHolder is involved, but if I do:
SecurityContext context= ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().block();
context is null... any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It returns null, if the user has not been authenticated. Make sure that user got authenticated before requesting for  request.getRemoteUser()

Comment: The user already authenticated.
I try in preHandle,postHandle,afterCompletion,
If i try to get the authentication from  ((SecurityContextImpl)sess.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT")).getAuthentication() it work but i need to get it from the request.
Thanks.